# using reservation identification number in python script

Tags: boto

When I initiate a new instance using boto, I get the reservation ID. But how do I use that reservation ID in the python script?

```
myreservation = conn.run_instances('ami-999c9999', placement='us-east-1a', key_name='nov15_key',instance_type='m1.xlarge',security_groups=['NuoDB-1-0-1-AutogenByAWSMP-'])
```

The next line does not work as expected:

```
myinstanceid = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'reservation-id':myreservation})[0].instances[0]
```

If I add the reservation ID in the code, it will work without any problem.

```
myinstanceid = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'reservation-id':'r-1e654a79'})[0].instances[0]
```

I will like to know what is the type of the reservation id and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, run_instances returns this:

Returns:
The boto.ec2.instance.Reservation associated with the request for machines

Reservation has, also according to [the docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.instance), an instances slot which contains a list of boto.ec2.instance.Instance objects.  It also has an "id" slot.

If you need the reservation id:

```
myreservation.id
```

And if you want the instance id:

```
myreservation.instances[0].id
```

So the Reservation object already has all the info you are looking for, no need to do a followup lookup call.  But if you need to, you may want to try this:

```
myinstance = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'reservation-id':myreservation.id})[0]
```

Or better yet, this:

```
myinstanceid = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'reservation-id':myreservation.id})[0].id
```